# Invalid use of non-static member function when using cpp class

Tags: c++

I have an callback function :

```
ARCONTROLLER_Device_SetVideoStreamCallbacks (deviceController, decoderConfigCallback, didReceiveFrameCallback, NULL , NULL);
```

Which `decoderConfigCallback` and `didReceiveFrameCallback` are function.

When myproject have only a main.h and a main.cpp and define (without any class declaration)

```
    eARCONTROLLER_ERROR didReceiveFrameCallback (ARCONTROLLER_Frame_t *frame, void *customData);

 eARCONTROLLER_ERROR decoderConfigCallback (ARCONTROLLER_Stream_Codec_t codec, void *customData);
```

In .h file . when I call the `ARCONTROLLER_Device_SetVideoStreamCallbacks` evry thing is ok . but when I'll use a cpp class and do these, I get this error:

> invalid use of non-static member function

Comment: We need to see more code to understand the problem. But pretty sure you are not using classes in your "main only" case, in which case the functions are equivalent to static methods (as they don't rely on an instance of a class)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).